# Error while clicking on "Start Moodle.exe"

Tags: xampp, moodle

Moodle has been running in my machine without any error but today when I opened it by pressing "Start Moodle.exe", I received the following error. Could anyone help me why am I getting this? I have been developing a LTI tool for Moodle.

```
 ########################################################################
  # ApacheFriends XAMPP setup win32 Version                              #
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------#
  # Copyright (c) 2002-2019 Apachefriends ?.?.?                          #
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------#
  # Authors: Kay Vogelgesang <kvo@apachefriends.org>                     #
  #          Carsten Wiedmann <webmaster@wiedmann-online.de>             #
  ########################################################################



 Sorry, but ... nothing to do!



XAMPP now starts as a console application.

Instead of pressing Control-C in this console window, please use xampp_stop.exe
to stop XAMPP, because it lets XAMPP end any current transactions and cleanup
gracefully.

2019-01-23 11:51:23 6924 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 10.1.28-MariaDB) starting as process 8112 ...
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Comment: Sounds like either a previous instance of it is still running and using port 443, or something else has started using port 443. Try command netstat to see what is using port 443.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed port 443 to 444 in the file server/apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf and it starts working fine.